# How to launch Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows 10 S?

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I found the Ubuntu app button in Microsoft App Store and attached it. There were limited instructions: I had Microsoft Windows help with their side. Ubuntu did not boot up as option. Windows 10 S booted again, but I had a Linux command window. That's it.

Below are instructions from the official [Get Ubuntu 18.04 – Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804/9n9tngvndl3q?activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab) website.

> To launch, use "ubuntu1804" on the command line prompt (cmd.exe), or click on the Ubuntu icon tile in the Windows 10 Start menu.
>
> To use this feature, one first needs to use "Turn Windows features on or off" and select "Windows Subsystem for Linux", click OK, reboot, and use this app.

Over 214MB of data was installed when I clicked on the Ubuntu icon.

Then I opened the Windows command prompt window and typed `ubuntu 1804`, but nothing happened. My Windows Command Prompt results are shown below.

```
C:\Users\phoebedavis>UBUNTU 1804
'UBUNTU' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\phoebedavis>
```

Can someone assist this totally new noob?  I want to run Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows 10 S before buying multiple single board computers and installing Ubuntu on them as workstations.

Comment: Could you please remove CAPSLOCK from your question? What do you want to achieve? Do you want to remove Windows and install Ubuntu instead? Do you want to install Ubuntu inside Windows using VirtualBox? Do you want to have both Windows and Ubuntu installed on physical hardware (dual-boot)?

Comment: Have you tried typing `ubuntu` into the Cortana search box?

Comment: gentlemen, I am sorry. I included all documentation at beginning for your reference.  basically running Microsoft windows v10S. I did Turn Windows features on or off" and select "Windows Subsystem for Linux", click OK, reboot. when I clicked on the the app button a window came up command line. I used 'alton' as root and entered a password. was accepted.  but UBUNTU never came up as a program.  However over 214MB of data installed when I clicked on the Ubunto icon.   which ever is easiest. I want to run both windows and/or ubuntu full package.  I am not a programmer nor have knowledge to cmds.

Comment: I need clear commands to enter into that window to launch the actual ubuntu1804 package.  (ubuntu104 from cmd exe does not work either.)   so sorry please assist.

Comment: Windows 10 S does *not* support WSL.

Answer (score 7):

[Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804/9n9tngvndl3q) allows one to use Ubuntu Terminal and run Ubuntu command line utilities including bash, ssh, git, apt and many more. Ubuntu 18.04 WSL is published by Canonical. The Windows 10 April 2019 Update gives Windows Subsystem for Linux the new ability to let you access Linux files safely from Windows. WSL2 which features a true Linux kernel can be installed in Windows 10 version 2004 and later.

**Please note that Windows 10 S does not support running this app.** *Windows 10 in S Mode can’t use command-line shells like PowerShell, Command Prompt, or Bash which are commonly used in WSL. Various other developer tools are also off limits.*<sup>**[*](https://www.howtogeek.com/354057/what-is-windows-10-in-s-mode/)**</sup>

The options for running Ubuntu in Windows 10 S are either in a virtual machine like VirtualBox or as a dual boot alongside Windows 10 S.

Comment: +1 because I never heard of "S". A quick google search made me think it means "poor **S**tudent". But I wonder how **UBUNTU** is different than normal *ubuntu* in normal *WSL*? I just use normal Ubuntu in normal Windows 10 normal WSL myself. Albeit with abnormal GUI under **VcXsrv**.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix *Windows 10 in S Mode can’t use command-line shells like PowerShell, Command Prompt, or Bash which are commonly used in WSL. Various other developer tools are also off limits.* For more information read this source article: [What is Windows 10 in S Mode?](https://www.howtogeek.com/354057/what-is-windows-10-in-s-mode/).

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft: *Windows 10S is not able to use command prompt or any settings that can alter system files for security purposes. The only way for you to do this is to upgrade/switch to Windows 10 Pro.*
(Source: [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/command-prompt-in-windows-10s/cac12ce6-f6c6-4585-90bb-9240ef04436e))

Moreover, for WSL to work you need to have `cmd` or *powershell*. So, I would suggest you to either install Ubuntu in VMWare or upgrade to Windows 10 Home/Pro.

Comment: Thx everyone!  I installed it on windows 7 virtually.  Windows 10s (newest) has to be altered by Microsoft help, even though you set it up for virtual window environment.  I am sold on KUBUNTU! Awesome!  Not sure how to mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it directly from CMD, at least if you're on wsl2. I found this by adding the command line column in task manager and expanding the Ubuntu process.

I was able to type "wsl.exe ~ -d Ubuntu-20.04" to boot directly into the console from CMD.

This may vary depending on your version of ubuntu but I imagine it would run the same given you change the version number. I am going to make the above code a bat file so I don't have to type that every time ^_^. sorry for the late reply but I hope this can assist you or others in future!

Comment: Note that this question is about running WSL on Windows 10S, which simply [will not work](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/will-linux-distros-run-on-windows-10-s/).