# Installing ubuntu usinng wubi.exe taking me to grub menu

Tags: wubi, 18.10

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 using wubi.exe on Windows 10. Restarted the system after installation and it took me to grub menu.

What should I do get out of Grub menu and boot to Ubuntu?

Comment: This is one big reason why Microsoft released [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067924/how-to-launch-ubuntu-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-in-windows-10-s/1067936#1067936) on Windows 10.

Comment: But that's very slow as compared to Ubuntu. @karel, You are saying that its not possible in windows 10?

Comment: Installing Ubuntu 18.10 with wubi.exe is not possible in Windows 10. Your alternatives on Windows 10 are Ubuntu 18.04 with WSL, VM or dual boot.

Comment: An alternative is to install Ubuntu in a **virtual machine** (for example, you can install VirtualBox in Windows, and create a virtual machine with a virtual drive and file system). But it will be slow, unless the computer is powerful and has a lot of RAM. Another alternative is to run Ubuntu **persistent live or an installed Ubuntu system in a fast USB3 drive or USB SSD**, or finally, if you are ready for it, shrink a Windows partition and **install Ubuntu alongside Windows in the internal drive, a dual boot** system.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Ubuntu 18.10 with wubi.exe is not possible in Windows 10. Your alternatives on Windows 10 are Ubuntu 18.04 with [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067924/how-to-launch-ubuntu-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-in-windows-10-s/1067936#1067936) (WSL), VM or dual boot.

Please note that Windows 10 S does not support running WSL. Windows 10 in S Mode can’t use command-line shells like PowerShell, Command Prompt, or Bash which are commonly used in WSL. Various other developer tools are also off limits.